# MPMoviePlayerController playing, but playbackstate is paused

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a strange stuation: after setting *currentPlaybackTime* in *MPMoviePlayerController* and play it after changing, the *playbackState* still paused (video and music are playing).
I'm using a NSTimer for checking playbackState.

Comment: You might want to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS 5? If so, a similar issue is reported here on the Open Radar site: http://openradar.appspot.com/10484668

A suggested fix mentioned is to make sure that the call to setContentURL is made before setting the currentPlaybackTime.